# How to improved readability when accessing rows in homogeneous row-major NumPy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a concept of a `trajectory` in my code.   It consists of `N` points in space, each having 7 pieces of data, `s` (path length), `x`, `y`, `z` (position) and `tx`, `ty`, `tz` (tangent vectors).  I want to store these data in a `numpy.array`.  Numpy is by default row-major, and I want each of these labels to be a row, for optimal access.  This is because I will often not be accessing individual points, but instead mostly operating on each row (`s`, `x`, etc.) as a whole.

What I can do is like `trajectory = np.zeros((7, N))` and then access each row by doing `trajectory[6]` and then calculate what I want.  However I hate how unreadable this is.  I don't find raw index-based access to be readable at all, and my eyes glaze over when I look at a numpy expression and see a load of these index-based accesses performing some calculation.  The obvious thing to do then is access them with names in some way.  I looked at structured arrays but these are more for heterogeneous datatypes, with the structs aligned in memory, so that for example `z` and `tx` would be next to each other, which is not in the spirit of what I want.  You could say, just let them be different arrays entirely then (i.e. 7 different arrays), but then I would lose some nice operations where it makes sense to treat them as a single array.

So is it possible to have more human-readable array access in numpy for homogeneous data?  If not exactly, what is a common solution to make more readable numpy code without `y = x[1] + x[4] * x[3]` etc. everywhere?

Comment: you can look into the package xarray, http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

Comment: A structured array 'packs' the fields together, so the array would be `(N,)` with the 7 values of each `point` together.  It is possible `view` such an array as `(N,7)`, but loose that "row-major" benefit (which may not be that signficant).

Comment: With your (7,N) array, you could define `s=trajectory[0]`, `x=tranjectory[1]`, etc. and do `yx+tx*z`.  Those `s`,`x` are views, so in-place changes will be seen in `trajectory`.

Comment: xarray is one option; wasnt mature enough when I last looked at it, but that was years ago. However, what about just making a little enum_constants.py, that you import * whenever in a relevant scope? Note that while numpy has its memory layout defaults, you can perfectly well customize the striding, so if you want to write x[:, S] you could perfectly well have that as a contiguous view too.